# How to store results from IBM SQL Query service into IBM Db2 on Cloud?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools, ibm-cloud-storage, ibm-cloud-sql-query

I have a question regarding using IBM SQL Query service to query IBM Db2 on Cloud. Let's say I have a query statement that is running on the IBM SQL Query console I want to make a connection to IBM Db2 on Could from SQL Query service so that I can save the query result into the database. 
I have created the IBM SQL Query service and Db2 on Cloud lite instance.

Can you guys help me with how it would be possible?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://blog.4loeser.net/2019/11/etl-in-cloud-using-sql-query-and-db2.html What are the **technical** questions?

Comment: It works for me, thanks @data_henrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data_henrik has already provided a good blog resource for that.

For formal documentation see here https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/sql-query?topic=sql-query-overview#db-location

Also check out the Db2 target samples in the "Samples"->/ETL & ELT queries" pull down in the UI.