# How to flatten an Parquet Array datatype when using IBM Cloud SQL Query

Tags: db2, parquet, ibm-cloud-sql-query

I have to push parquet file data which I am reading from IBM Cloud SQL Query to Db2 on Cloud.

My parquet file has data in array format, and I want to push that to DB2 on Cloud too.

Is there any way to push that array data of parquet file to Db2 on Cloud?

Comment: Db2 does not have native support for reading Parquet files. Maybe try IBM Cloud SQL Query to read the file and push data into Db2 on Cloud  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60826842/how-to-store-results-from-ibm-sql-query-service-into-ibm-db2-on-cloud

Comment: yes, i am using IBM cloud Sql query for reading parquet file and pushing data into db2, but problem is that in my parquet file there is some array data also so that is not pushing into db2. So how to push that array that which is in parquet file..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out this advise in the documentation?

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/sql-query?topic=sql-query-overview#limitations

> If a JSON, ORC, or Parquet object contains a nested or arrayed
>   structure, a query with CSV output using a wildcard (for example,
>   SELECT * from cos://...) returns an error such as "Invalid CSV data
>   type used: struct." Use one of the following
>   workarounds:
>
> - For a nested structure, use the FLATTEN table transformation function.
> - Alternatively, you can specify the fully nested column names
>     instead of the wildcard, for example, `SELECT address.city, address.street, ... from cos://....`
> - For an **array**, use the Spark SQL explode() function, for example, `select explode(contact_names) from cos://....`